# Update bootstrap datetime widget to set date

Tags: javascript, datepicker, momentjs, bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I'm using the [Bootstrap datetimepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) in one of our projects. It is a MVC application and it hides the date input by default and shows the bootstrap datetime picker.

The problem we have now is that we're not able to set the date that's set in the date field in the widget. It always loads today.

eg:

1. I load the form in the browser
2. I choose a date in the datetime picker
3. I submit the form with a error
4. The page is reloaded and the datepicker is set to today, the input value is the correct day and if I navigate to the date in the datepicker is shows up as selected.

I've read through the documentation and tried to use the update function and the `setdate` function but they didn't do a thing and also didn't return a error.

What I expect it to do is show the selected date if the input is filled.

Now I'm stuck.

*edit:*

I use a input type="text" on the page with a classname datePickerInline.
On that class there's a css style that hides the input and the following script is present:

/* Document Ready Inits */

```
$(function () {
    initDatePickers();
});

/* Bindings */
function initDatePickers() {
    $('.datePickerInline').datetimepicker({
        inline: true,
        keepOpen: true,
        debug: true,
        locale: 'nl'
    });
}
```

The input can be prefilled with a date. That works like a charm. If I for example get `$('.datePickerInline').val()` and try to add setDate in the datetimepicker method it doesn't work. I cant get .update() to work. It errors out all the time.

The stupid thing is that the date is set correctly but the widget wont "scroll" to the correct page...

Comment: Can you please add some code snippet showing what you tried and how you used the datetimepicker?

Comment: I've put the code in the OP in a edit.

Comment: What do you mean with _errors out all the time_? What kind of errors do you get? Can you add your html and the code you used to `setDate` and gives you error?